# LinkedList vector constructor not working as expected

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to implement a LinkedList constructor that takes a vector of a certain types as a parameter and converts it to a linked list. In my testing I create a vector of ints (0-9) and pass it to my constructor. However when I try to print out the values instead of getting : {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0} I am getting {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 019941456, 0, }. With that random number changing every time. I am not sure what i'm doing wrong but I'm sure it's something with me not fully understanding pointers and addresses. I'm not sure how to fix it or where to go from here. Sorry for the formatting I'm new and not sure how to color the text, thank you in advance.

Linked List Class

```
template<typename ElementType>
class LinkedList {

  /*
   *  Declare any struct, class, or enum types you need to use here
   */
private:
    typedef struct node {
        ElementType val;
        node *next;
        node(ElementType input) : val(input), next(nullptr) {};
        node() {};
    }* LinkedListNode;

    int list_size = 0;                                                   // size variable for ease
public:
    LinkedListNode head;                                                  // Head of list
    LinkedList();                                                   // Default constructor
    explicit LinkedList(const std::vector<ElementType> &values);    // Initilize from vector

    // Big 5
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& source);                                           // Copy constructor
    LinkedList(LinkedList&& source) noexcept;                                       // Move constructor
    ~LinkedList();                                                                  // Destructor
    LinkedList<ElementType>& operator=(const LinkedList<ElementType>& source);      // Copy assignment operator
    LinkedList<ElementType>& operator=(LinkedList<ElementType>&& source) noexcept;  // Move assignment operator

    void push_front(ElementType value);         // Push value on front
    void push_back(ElementType value);          // Push value on back
    ElementType front() const;                  // Access the front value
    ElementType back() const;                   // Access the back valueW
    void pop_front();                           // remove front element
    void pop_back();                            // remove back element
    int size() const;                           // return number of elements
    bool empty() const;                         // check if empty
    void clear();                               // clear the contents
    void RemoveOdd();                           // remove the odd elements from the list 0 indexed
    bool operator==(const LinkedList<ElementType> &rhs) const;
  .
  .
  .
};
```

Constructor method:

```
template<typename ElementType>
LinkedList<ElementType>::LinkedList(const std::vector<ElementType> &values) {
    if (values.size() == 0) {
        head = NULL;
    } else {
        for (auto current_value : values) {
            push_front(current_value);
        }
    }
}
```

push_front method:

```
template<typename ElementType>
void LinkedList<ElementType>::push_front(ElementType value) {
    LinkedListNode new_node = new node(value);
    new_node -> next = head;
    head = new_node;                                       // Add to beginning
    list_size++;
}
```

Comment: Pretend that your vector has only one value. Now, take a piece of paper and a pencil, and work out, on paper, the following three problems: where the final, constructed list's `head` will point to. And where the linked list's only element's `next` pointer will point to. And what you expect the sole list element's `next` value to point to. Once you figure out what the answers to these three questions are, you should be able to figure out the bug in the shown code.

Comment: Is this line verbatim from your code ```new_node -> next = head```? Without looking too deeply at the rest of your code this should break your code. If p is some pointer, then ```(*p).member``` or ```p->```––no spaces.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you @SamVarshavchik .

Comment: @eric I'm not sure I understand, are the spaces the problem then? So you're saying I should be using p-> or p.next instead of p -> next?

Comment: Spaces are not the problem here.

Comment: If I'm thinking correctly the `head` will point to null, and the element's `next` points to `head`. I expect the element's `next` to point to null though so why is that not fine? Sorry if I'm not following well.

Comment: Have a closer look at your code in the constructor, what value does `head` have the first time `push_front` is called?

Comment: The answer is garbage. head does not point to any valid node.

Comment: I didn't mean to throw you off the actual problem. Spaces are not **the** problem, but yeah. @TheDark gave a good hint.

Comment: Oh, should I be initializing `head` to point to null before the loop? Also, should I be using NULL or nullptr?   EDIT: That was the problem, thank you guys so much! (still wondering about NULL vs nullptr).

Comment: `nullptr` was introduced to replace`NULL`. Modern code should use nullptr. https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/28/migrating-from-c-to-c-null-vs-nullptr